# Adicionar coluna MySQL com incremento para não repetir

Tags: php, mysql

Minha intenção é pegar uma variável via *POST* e mudar o valor dela.

```
$vem = $_POST['nome'];

if (isset($vem)){

    $vem = 1;
    $vem++;
    $vem = 'campo'.$vem;
}
```

Vou adicionar como coluna de uma tabela dentro dessa mudança

```
$vem = $_POST['nome'];

if (isset($vem)){

$vem = 1;
    $vem++;
    $vem = 'campo'.$vem;

$sqli = mysql_query ("ALTER TABLE  grafica ADD $vem varchar(255)")  or die(mysql_error());
if($sqli){

     echo 'salvou '.$vem;
 }

}
```

Até ai tudo *ok*! O que preciso é que ele entenda que já tem a coluna `campo.2` e adicione a coluna `campo.3`

Comment: Tente pegar primeiro os nomes das colunas. Dá uma olhada nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15671366/6754506), [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091984/6754506) e [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19684307/6754506)

Comment: na verdade so preciso saber se tem a coluna, o nome da coluna estou mudando qdo vem o POST, tipo um select e depois um consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de tudo, tenho alguns pontos para colocar:

1. Nomes de colunas com `.` não são nada comuns
2. Se uma tabela `X` tem diversos campos nesse formato (`campo1`, `campo2`, `campo3`), considere normalizar e criar uma tabela `X_Campo`, onde você teria um `id`, uma chave para a tabela `X` e uma coluna com o valor propriamente dito.
3. Procure não usar as funções `mysql_*`, use no lugar ao menos as `mysqli_`. Elas foram descontinuadas...

Minha solução seria essa aqui:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<pre>
<?php
// conecta no bd
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;  
} else {
  echo 'conexão: ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

  // primeiro, precisamos saber dos campos da tabela. A query não precisa retornar nada, só precisamos do metadata inicialmente.
  $tableName = 'tabela';
  $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE 0");
  if ($res) {
    $numeroNovoCampo = 1;
    $prefixoNovoCampo = 'campo';
    $fields = $res->fetch_fields();
    echo "verificando nomes dos campos pelo prefixo '$prefixoNovoCampo'...\n";
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
      printf("%s\n", $field->name);
      $pos = strpos($field->name, $prefixoNovoCampo);
      if ($pos !== false) {
        $apos = substr($field->name, strlen($prefixoNovoCampo) + $pos);
        echo "encontrou o prefixo, verifica o que está depois ($apos)\n";
        $numero = intval($apos);
        $numeroNovoCampo = max($numeroNovoCampo, $numero+1);
      }
    }
    $sql = "ALTER TABLE $tableName ADD $prefixoNovoCampo$numeroNovoCampo varchar(255)";
    echo "criando campo com nome $prefixoNovoCampo$numeroNovoCampo: $sql\n";
    $altTab = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($altTab) {
      echo "campo criado com sucesso\n";
    } else {
      echo "deu um erro? " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    }
    $res->close();
  } else {
    echo "erro na consulta\n";
  }
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
</pre>
</html>
```

Criei uma tabela pra testar aqui e coloquei alguns `campoN` só pra ver como ficaria, e tive essa saída:

```
conexão: localhost via TCP/IP
verificando nomes dos campos pelo prefixo 'campo'...
id
id_usuario
usuario
momento
random
valor
campo1
encontrou o prefixo, verifica o que está depois (1)
campo2
encontrou o prefixo, verifica o que está depois (2)
campo3
encontrou o prefixo, verifica o que está depois (3)
criando campo com nome campo4
campo criado com sucesso
```

Comment: perfeito, adptei no que preciso e deu certo, obg!

Answer (score 2):

update 08/06/2018 22:59

> Essa parte é totalmente dispensável e não serve para nada

```
$vem = 1;
    $vem++;
    $vem = 'campo'.$vem;
```

> pelas razões abaixo elencadas

1. é bastante óbvio que do jeito que está, a variável `$vem` sempre será `campo2`
2. se você quer nomes de colunas sequencias não há porque digitar um numero qualquer no campo a ser enviado via post. Exemplo, supor que tenha sido digitado o numero 8 e que temos as colunas campo.1, campo.2 e campo.3 na tabela, portanto a próxima coluna a ser criada é campo.4 e o numero enviado via post não foi aproveitado para nada.

Essa variável `$vem` oriunda de `$_POST['nome'];` pode ser, por exemplo, um prefixo dos nomes das colunas a serem criadas, dando margem a criar colunas com vários prefixos e sequencialmente, como por exemplo campo.1, campo.2, etc.. ou qqnome.1, qqnome.2, etc...e tal

Não é comum nomear colunas com `.` e isso pode causar erros caso não seja tratado corretamente na declaração `ALTER TABLE`. Neste caso é imprescindível envolver o nome da coluna com aspas invertidas que nada mais são que o acento crase do seu teclado. Maiores detalhes em [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE $table ADD `$nomeProxColuna` varchar(255)";
```

**Código proposto**

> com `Mysqli` porque `mysql_*` foi descontinuado e
>   Nomes de colunas sem `.`

```
$vem = $_POST['nome'];

if (isset($vem)){

    $hostname="localhost";  
    $db_user="USUARIO";  
    $db_pw="SENHA";  
    $db_name = "nome_DB";  

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost',$db_user,$db_pw,$db_name);

    //nome da tabela
    $table = 'artigos';

    /**
    * Obtem os nomes das colunas com prefixo = $vem (vindo do post)
    **/

      $sql = 'DESCRIBE '.$table;
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

      $rows = array();
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         //cria array com nomes das colunas que contem a palavra $vem
         $texto = $row['Field'];
         if (strstr($texto, $vem)){;
            $rows[] = $row['Field'];
         }

      }

      /********** caso haja nomes de colunas com prefixo vindo do post
       prepara o nome da proxima coluna *****************************/

      if($rows){
          /*****retorna maior valor do array dado pela parte numérica
          já que a parte anterior à numérica é/são igual(is) *******/

          $maior = max($rows);

         /********próximo nome da coluna********/

         //comprimento da variavel vindo do post
         $len=strlen($vem);

         //pega a parte numérica do nome dado pela variável $maior definida acima
         $proxNum = substr($maior,$len)+1;

         //cria o nome da próxima coluna
         $nomeProxColuna = $vem.$proxNum;

      }else{ 

         //se não existem colunas com prefixo vindo do post cria a primeira

         $nomeProxColuna=$vem."1";

      }

    //  altera a estrutura da tabela acrescentando campos

    $sql = "ALTER TABLE $table ADD `$nomeProxColuna` varchar(255)";

    $incluirColuna = $con->query($sql);
    if ($incluirColuna) {
      echo "coluna criada com sucesso\n";
    } else {
      echo "deu zebra: " . $con->error . "\n";
    }     

}
```

> Se os prefixos dos nomes das colunas serão sempre os mesmos, basta colocá-lo como valor da variável `$vem`. Exemplo `$vem="campo";`
>
> e as primeiras linhas do código, por exemplo, ficam

```
if (isset($_POST['criarColuna'])) {

   $vem="campo";
```

> e no formulário somente um input/botão, exemplo  `<input type="submit" name="criarColuna" value="Criar coluna">`

Comment: entendi, porem no if, como vou adicionar um incremento a mais, pra nao dar coluna duplicada e adicionar no bd com um numero a mais, ex... foi a 3, a proxima é a 4

Comment: Neste caso voltamos a pergunta original certo?

Comment: e ele nao deu o echo "existe"...rs nao me retorna a consulta

Comment: Se não deu é porque não existe!

Comment: Coloca um print_r($rows); e veja o que retorna